# How to show and hide wizard button based on condition?

Tags: python, xml, odoo-14

Show and hide Cost Price List per warehouse based on condition
If res.config.settings is_cost_price_per_warehouse = TRUE AND product.template -> product.category property_cost_method = [average]
product.template (and/or product.product) standard_price is HIDDEN
Show “Cost Price List” hyperlink
Else
Do like existing

Comment: Dear Jogi, you should show some code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example